# length of dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

I declared a dynamic array like this:

```
int *arr = new int[n];   //n is entered by user
```

Then used this to find length of array:

```
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

It gives `len` as `1` instead of `n` . Why is it so?

Comment: Just use vector, you will save your self a lot of time.

Comment: `int *arr = new int[n];` is declaring a pointer. `std::vector<int> arr;` is declaring a dynamic array.

Comment: You don't have a dynamic array -- you only have a pointer to the first element of a dynamic array.

Comment: @KerrekSB Other than using vector as an alternative, is there a way to find length of dynamic array.

Comment: @Jatin No, there is no way. You have to store the length and pass it where necessary.

Comment: @Jatin: No. *You*'re the one who specified the length in the first place, so you should be the one remembering it.

Comment: @Jatin, What does it give you, if you take:

int lenArr = sizeof(arr);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `arr` is not an array, but a pointer, and you are running on an architecture where size of pointer is equal to the size of `int`.

Answer (score 12):

Because `sizeof` does not work for dynamic arrays. It gives you the size of `pointer`, since `int *arr` is a pointer

You should store the size of allocated array or better use `std::vector`

Comment: Is something like this valid `int arr[n]` where n is entered by user?

Comment: @Jatin: `n` must be `const` or `const-expression`. Otherwise it will not compile since the compiler does not know how much memory to allocate at compile time

Comment: surprisingly, It compiles on code::blocks

Comment: @Jatin Set your compiler to standards-compliant mode and turn all the warnings on (`-std=c++98` or `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` and all of `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`). It probably compiles because of a GNU extension.

Comment: @Jatin gcc has VLAs in C++ as an extension, I think Code::Blocks uses gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right.
You have to save **n** somewhere (depends on where do you use it). Or if you are using .NET you could use Array or List...